# FullCalendar - How to make a "agendaWeek" view increase the first day it displays?

Tags: fullcalendar

Using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) with the "[agendaWeek](https://fullcalendar.io/views/agendaWeek/)" view, I'd like the `next` button to increase the first *day* displayed by the calendar.

In other words, instead of displaying the next *week* when the `next` button is clicked, I'd like the day of the first column to increase!

**Example**

If the calendar displays:

```
Sun 6/8 | Mon 6/9 | Tue 6/10 | Wed 6/11 | Thu 6/12 | Fri 6/13 | Sat 6/14
```

After a click on the `next` button, I'd like to see :

```
Mon 6/9 | Tue 6/10 | Wed 6/11 | Thu 6/12 | Fri 6/13 | Sat 6/14 | Sun 6/15
```

---

Same thing when I click the `previous` button : I'd like the first day to become the *previous one*, not one week before.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found it : [Generic Views](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Generic_Views/).

```
defaultView: 'agenda',
duration: {days: 7},
dateIncrement: "24:00"
```